# Attacked by black belt

Tags: jujutsu

I was attacked in the street by my neighbour who is a black belt Tai Juitsu,
I want to know how I go about getting his licence revoked.
He is claiming self defence only because I tried to get him of me while he had his hands round my neck using his thumbs to push my adams apple into the back of my throat.

Regards

Michael

Comment: What? A little more context would be useful.

Comment: I'm not sure if people who do Tai-jutsu have a license that can be revoked. I think it's best to report it to the police and let them sort it out.

Comment: While we can certainly sympathize with you regarding this, it is an extremely localized and subjective question which is not a good fit for the site. I would speculate that you are also missing detail from the question - people seldom attack without at least some sort of trigger event. In any case local law enforcement should be your first recourse. If you want you can edit and rephrase your question at which point we can consider reopening it.

Comment: Stop worrying about "revoking" his "license"; just see if you can track down his teacher and tell that person what happened.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you`re comments. Yes I may provoked the attack by telling his wife to f@@K off my property as she was having a go at my wife for something stupid. It was very obvious to me he knew what he was doing as he was strangling me he was pushing my adams apple in to my throat, so now it`s very difficult to swallow and I have bruises around my whole neck. Yes I did call the police but that`s was a waste of time . Thanks Again. @Trevoke , @THelper , @slugster , @Dave liepmann

Answer (score 2):

In most places, black belts do not have special licences to do anything. As such, you wouldn't be able to get his licence revoked.

What you can do, however, is file a complain to your local police department. If indeed he tried to strangle you while you had not acted menacingly (some places recognize pre-emptive self defense as valid if the threat was severe), this qualifies for assault under most laws and you, in fact, **should** report such behavior to the authorities.

Undergoing strangulation is good grounds for claiming self defense, especially if your opponent, as you claim, knew exactly what he was doing. If you chose to report the assault to the proper authorities, I would strongly advise you to be passively cooperative, and let the investigators to their job without interference. Self defense claims are not always so easy to judge if there is no evidence or witnesses, and police officers are often wary of these cases; being pushy about the investigation will not help you at all.